# GridView Page Index Change Event causes JavaScript runtime error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

On Page Index Change Event of GridView, the following error is caused.

```
JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500
```

The gridview is inside an update panel and there are following AsyncPostbackTriggers:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvKnowledgeDetails" 
                            EventName="PageIndexChanged" />
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvKnowledgeDetails" 
                            EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvKnowledgeDetails" EventName="RowCommand" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdateKnowledgeDetails" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCancelV" />
                            </Triggers>
```

I an unable to find any solutions to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your ScriptManager control, add the following attribute and it's value:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false" />
```

Comment: Can you explain what was causing this error and how was it resolved? Thanks in advance.